# 404 Not Found static files React JS | NGINX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx

I want to make my site available on a domain without port 3000, I know that React JS and Nginx cannot use the same ports, so below you can see the configuration of my Nginx file:

```
location / {
   # try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
     proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /static/ {
     proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

When I go to https://example.com I see a blank page and the following errors in the console:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aR6f.png)

But when I go to http://example.com:3000 it all works without any issues, so how can I make it work on https://example.com?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume you are running the react app using `npm run start`/`yarn start`, which is intended for your development environment. Running the app on your server, however, brings it to "production".

Running `npm run build`/`yarn build` gives you all your source files in a compiled and optimized format. You can put them on your server and let them be served by nginx right away (like using the `try_files`) without the need for running a separate server or passing the request as a proxy.

If you would like to run your app only as a proxy anyway (e.g. it’s your dev environment), you have to fix the paths in your nginx config, because your `/static/` location does not forward to the proxys `/static/` path. You can do so by either adding the path to `proxy_pass` or by removing the complete second location block — it will be equivalent to the first one.

For your reference:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/
- https://blog.devgenius.io/using-nginx-to-serve-react-application-static-vs-proxy-69b85f368e6c

Comment: Im running it using "yarn start", if I remove second location block "location /static/" nothing changes, problem persists

Comment: Okay, substitute `npm run` with `yarn` in my post ;)
Have you done `sudo service nginx reload` after changing the config? Just to be sure…

Comment: sure, i've done service nginx restart multiple times